# DBSight does not work on Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

Does anyone have dbsight running successfully on linux under tomcat?
It works fine on windows, on linux however all the pages spit out garbage characters. In itself, the app appears to deploy normally.
The tomcat uri encoding is set to utf-8 on both windows and linux.

the lang is set to en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I notice you also posted this question on the DBSight web page - good.  That was smart :)

You say you set $LANG to "en_US.UTF-8" in your environment, and in server.xml.  That's good.  Please note that Linux is case-sensitive: the variable *must* be spelled "LANG", not "lang", or "lAnG", or anything else.

One other issue might be "LC_ALL" - this can override the value of "$LANG":

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fae19494_.htm

If you're still having a problem, please specify what kind of Linux (Redhat Enterprise?  Ubuntu?  etc) and version (e.g. Ubuntu Server 11.1).

Comment: thanks for your response - the LC_ALL is not set at all, the OS version is

Comment: (and the LANG env var is all capital:))